# How do I access information about my samsungs app activities from months back

Tags: applications, samsung, hardware

How do I access information about my samsungs app activities from months back. What apps I used and for how long? I need this information for school.I know about the 7 day interval. I want to find information about the 25th of Oct.

Plz HELP!!!